# Create a faster regular expression clr function

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I am trying to improve the Clr function in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx .

```
public static partial class UserDefinedFunctions 
{
    public static readonly RegexOptions Options =
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
        RegexOptions.Singleline;

    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlBoolean RegexMatch(
        SqlChars input, SqlString pattern)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex( pattern.Value, Options );
        return regex.IsMatch( new string( input.Value ) );
    }
}
```

When execute `select * from Table1 where dbo.RegexMatch(col1, 'pattern') = 1`, the Clr function create a new Regex object for each row in the table.

Is it possible to create only one Regex object for each Sql statement? For each row just call `regex.Ismatch(...)`.  Is the following code valid?

```
public static partial class UserDefinedFunctions 
{
    public static readonly RegexOptions Options =
        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
        RegexOptions.Singleline;

    static Regex regex = null;

    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlBoolean RegexMatch(
        SqlChars input, SqlString pattern)
    {
        if (regex == null) 
            regex = new Regex( pattern.Value, Options );
        return regex.IsMatch( new string( input.Value ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: The article suggests that if you use `RegexOptions.Compiled` then it might be cached - but I can't see any other evidence of that...

Comment: Interesting. The constructor of Regex will reuse the Regex instance if the it has the option of compiled and the same pattern? I was thinking of some Singleton pattern but not sure of the life of the singleton.

Comment: It wouldn't reuse the same actual *instance*, but it could reuse all the work done to create the previous instance.

Comment: You just put a race condition into SQL Server and destroyed its reliability. Concurrent queries will scribble over each others Regex. That's why it is disallowed. (Workarounds are available.)

Comment: msdn Link is dead.

Comment: Link available at https://web.archive.org/web/20111230084415/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UDF based instance of your static regex is probably not even re-used, Your better of calling the static version of

`System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.IsMatch(string input, string pattern, RegexOptions options);`

directly.

Please note that in debug mode things work different than that what they do in production and that SQL is going to free memory when it needs to.

Also, try using `RegexOptions.Compiled` and `CultureInvariant`.

Comment: The static overloads use a cache under the hood which is why this answer is good. +1

Comment: Curiously why the static  read-only method may not even be reused?